# Appium : New session could not be created

Tags: appium

I just started exploring Appium, I am trying to launch Amazon app in my nexus 9 and i am getting following error:
"*A new session could not be created. (Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity*"

My app is already installed in nexus devie and i also tried by checking/un-checking "Full reset"/"No reset" options

Here's my code:

```
File app = new File("D:\\Seleniumdownloads\\apk\\com.amazon.mShop.android.apk");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 9");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.1");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.amazon.mShop.android");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.android.HomeActivity");

            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.quit();
```

Please help where i am going wrong..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem lies in this line for sure:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.amazon.mShop.android.HomeActivity");
```

By looking at [some tutorial](http://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/first-appium-test-to-launch-amazon-app/), I think that the activity should be `com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity`. Check if it works.

You can download small free [APK Info app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intelloware.apkinfo) to see what are the app activities. Sometimes activity that is launched first does not have "Main" or "Home" word in name. For example, recently I tested app that has "*.MainActivity", but the activity that was started first was "*.LoginActivity" and that was the one that was used by Appium to start the app.

Good luck!

Comment: yup ur right i modified the activity and checked..its works fine..
thanks for suggestion.

If u know any good site for mobile testing beginner tutorials..please send me link.

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

When ever u get New session could not be created error just restart the eclipse once and try again.